# grails 2.2.2 platform-core-plugin No signature of method event in domain model

Tags: events, grails, grails-platform-core

I try out the platform-core-1.0 rc5 Plugin to services by events. Now I write a service in the grails-plugin "listadmin":

```
package listadmin

class SECO_ListenService {

    @grails.events.Listener(topic='getEntriesOfList', namespace='listadmin')
    def getEntriesOfList(String intnalListName) {
        println "SECO_ListenService"
        def Liste aList = Liste.findByInternal_name(intnalListName)
        return aList.eintrage.toList()
    }
}
```

This service should return a list for dropdown in an other grails-plugin called "institutionadmin". I want to use this list of the service for a dropdown of a domain-model. I should mention that I use dynamic scaffolding. Now I try to call this event in the domain-model:

```
package institutionadmin
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException
class Einrichtung {

    Long einrichtungs_type
    Long type_of_conzept
    int anzahl_gruppen
    int anzahl_kinder_pro_Gruppe
    String offnungszeiten
    static hasMany = [rooms : Raum]
    static constraints = {
        def aList = []
        def reply = event(for:"listadmin", topic:"getEntriesOfList", data:"einrichtung_type").waitFor()

        aList = reply.value.toList()
        einrichtungs_type(inList: aList)
    }
}
```

If I try to run this application i get the following error:

> Caused by MissingMethodException: No signature of method: institutionadmin.Einrichtung.event() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[for:listadmin, topic:testEventBus]]
>   Possible solutions: ident(), every(), every(groovy.lang.Closure), count(), get(java.io.Serializable), print(java.lang.Object)

If call this event in a controller everything is fine and the documentation of this plugin describe that I can call events also in domain-models and services... This error-method tell me, that the class don't know the event method.

Do I have to configure anything else?

Should call the event in another way or where is my mistake?

Has anybody experiences with this module?

Answer (score 3):

The `event(...)` dynamic methods are not available on class (static) level.

You can pull the `grailsEvents` spring bean and call its `event()` method alternatively. You still have to get the bean from the application context statically though.

You could also use a custom validator instead, as you can get the current domain instance as a parameter, which should have the `event()` method injected.

something like this :

```
static myList = []
static constraints = {
    einrichtungs_type validator: { value, instance ->
        if(!myList){
            // cache it the first time you save/validate the domain
            // I would probably recommend you NOT to do this here though in 
            // real life scenario
            def reply = instance.event('blabla').get()
            myList = reply.value.toList()
        }

        return value in myList
    }
}
```

Anyway, In my case I would probably load the list elsewhere (in the `Bootstrap.groovy` for instance) and use it / inject it in my domain instead of doing in the constraints closure.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar kind of problem, I wanted to use the event call inside a service class which is going to call the listener in other service class. When I started my application I got the same error.What I did was, added the plugin(`platform-core:1.0.RC5`) entries in `BuildConfig.groovy` like below

```
plugins {

    build(":tomcat:$grailsVersion",
        ":platform-core:1.0.RC5") {
        export = false
    }
    compile ':platform-core:1.0.RC5'
    runtime ':platform-core:1.0.RC5'
}
```

Then I ran grails > clean and grails > compile on that project and restarted the server.It started working. Might be you can give a try.